# How to detect ftp connection

Tags: linux, ftp, shell

I'm using vsftpd and I want to write a shell script that will detect a connection to my server and send me an email with information who and when has logged in.
I don't know where to start.  Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the log.

http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-3-Manual/ref-guide/s1-ftp-vsftpd-conf.html

Enable the transfer log.

Read the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with vsftpd, but you could have your shell script look at the output of [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) to see if you've got any connections on port 21 (the default ftp port).

Comment: Although with this he wouldn't know who logged in as requested in the question :(

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is using log analysis. If you use a tool like OSSEC (free and open source), it can run any scripts or generate email alerts when logins, logouts, failed logins, etc happens.

link: http://www.ossec.net

Answer (score 0):

Same applies for "fail2ban", though the purpose of this thing is something else (you guessed it).

J.